# How should I store this object in Redis?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, redis

```
parent = {
    child0: {
        data1:'foo',
        data2: 'bar'
    },
    child1: {
        data1:'foo',
        data2: 'bar'
    },
    child2: {
        data1:'foo',
        data2: 'bar'   
    }
}
```

At first I was thinking I would set a `parent:child` key since I will need that data individually of its siblings. In some instances though, I will need to return all of the data within parent.

Should I just put the whole object in a `parent` key?

Are there downsides to this if a lot of gets and sets may only be for one of it's children?

Is there a way to call all parent data with a `parent:child` schema?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a hash - that gives you HGET to get just one child and HGETALL to get all of them.

Storing the whole object as JSON in a single key is also valid though, and keeps your code simple if your usage is a good fit. If the numbers aren't too large, it may make sense to always retrieve the whole object even when you only need to display one child object.

The main reason to avoid storing complex objects in a single key is write conflicts - if two connections can modify different children of one object at the same time a hash will be much less trouble.

Comment: Ahh, yes, well all the children objects will be being edited at the same time. I should avoid this as much as possible on a single key?

Comment: yes - redis is fast enough that conflicts aren't that likely, but they will happen at the least convenient point and cause difficult to find bugs. With a hash or multiple keys each item is independent so conflicts are impossible.

Comment: Ah ok so if I use the hash features that will mitigate conflicts when two different children are being changed at the same time?

Comment: right, since redis handles them with separate atomic commands you only have to handle the possibility of two users modifying the same child, which is far less likely.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider taking advantage of the hash data type. Using the parent as a key to the hash and using (HGET key field) for a particular child or (HKEYS key) for all the children.

It would be interesting if someone would post benchmarks for hash commands HSET and HGET. The benchmarks for the list operations (LPUSH 88109.25 /sec) are (~23%) slower though (SET 114293.71 /sec). Presumably HSET is yet slower though listed O(1).

So I think you would speed optimize the decision by looking at the ratio of full family requests to individual child request in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. What if child processes will inherently be getting set at the same time. Can HGET/HSET manage these discrepancies?

Comment: Though I first thought you were talking about transactions, I think the HMSET command is what you are looking for when setting multiple hash values (children) at the same time.